# Using Pivot Table to reshape data in pandas so that multiple value appear below with their own lines

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, pivot-table

I have a dataframe that I am trying to pivot to get into long form. The executable code is below. But the output is not coming out the way I want it. I want the Amount and Quantity to be coming one below the other

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
        'Year':[2022,2022,2023,2023,2024,2024],
        'Month':[1,12,11,12,1,1],
        'Code':[None,'John Johnson',np.nan,'John Smith','Mary Williams','ted bundy'],
        'Unit Price':[np.nan,200,None,56,75,65],
        'Quantity':[1500, 140000, 1400000, 455, 648, 759],
        'Amount':[100, 10000, 100000, 5, 48, 59],
        'Invoice':['soccer','basketball','baseball','football','baseball','ice hockey'],
        'energy':[100.,100,100,54,98,3],
        'Category':['alpha','bravo','kappa','alpha','bravo','bravo']
})

index_to_use = ['Category','Code','Invoice','Unit Price']
values_to_use = ['Amount','Quantity']
columns_to_use = ['Year','Month']

df2 = df.pivot_table(index=index_to_use,
                            values=values_to_use,
                            columns=columns_to_use)
```

This output i want it so that the quantity is not to the right of the Amount but below and then I can sort it so, that the Quantity and Amount for the same (category, COde, Invoice, Unit Price) appear one below the other

```
                                                2022  
                                                 12
category   code   invoice   Unit Price  
                               200        Amount  10000  
                               200        Quantity   140000
```

the idea being that the Amount and Quantity sold of the same kind of articles (with same unit price)    appear on succeeding rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html#pandas.DataFrame.stack) your result:

```py
out = df2.stack(level=0)
```

Output:

```
Year                                                       2022   2023   2024
Month                                                        12     12     1
Category Code          Invoice    Unit Price
alpha    John Smith    football   56.0       Amount         NaN    5.0    NaN
                                             Quantity       NaN  455.0    NaN
bravo    John Johnson  basketball 200.0      Amount     10000.0    NaN    NaN
                                             Quantity  140000.0    NaN    NaN
         Mary Williams baseball   75.0       Amount         NaN    NaN   48.0
                                             Quantity       NaN    NaN  648.0
         ted bundy     ice hockey 65.0       Amount         NaN    NaN   59.0
                                             Quantity       NaN    NaN  759.0
```